# How to resize icons so that its responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I make icons automatically resize itself if i make the browser/screen smaller? Here's a part of my code and pictures of how it looks when displayed on a big screen and a small screen.

```
<div class="row mt">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 mb">
    <div class="green-panel pn">
      <div class="green-header">
        <h5>ADD NEW STUDENT</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="centered">
         <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/addstud'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div><! --/grey-panel -->
    </div><!-- /col-md-4-->

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 mb">
   <div class="green-panel pn">
    <div class="green-header">
     <h5>ADD NEW FACULTY</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="centered">
      <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/addfac'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><! --/grey-panel -->
  </div><!-- /col-md-4-->
```

Large screen:
[image: this is how it looks in a large screen]

Small screen:
[image: this is how it looks in a small screen]

Comment: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/ ... this would help you

Comment: @Ramanaa Gj I already tried this but it still wont get small every time I adjust the screen

Comment: try font-size in css (i.e) <i class="fa fa-user-plus" style="font-size:10px;"></i>

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can just reduce the font-size and the icon will be smaller.

example:

```
/* For screen width smaller than 768px */    
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .fa { 
    font-size: 18px; // or whatever size you want 
  }
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Font size alters the size of the glyphicons.

Comment: @mwan I tried to do this but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .centered .fa-user-plus { 
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```